# Ajax/Jquery Framework issues with xhr status=0 and xhr status=400

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

We are getting lot of Network and Application Errors after moving to Ajax/JQuery framework. The problem seems to be with higher volume of Webservices calls that are not being processed and return from the Browser itself. We put detailed logs for these Network errors and found that xhr=0 status is the most common occurence followed with xhr=400. The xhr=0 is happening across multiple browsers whereas the xhr=400 status code happens ONLY on IE browser and that too after it has been stuck for about 5 minutes. Would appreciate help from knowledgeable quarters in diagnosing this issue and fixing it.